# Pdflatex error when using {-" ... "-} inline TeX comments in lhs2TeX

Tags: haskell, literate-programming

I have the following code block in my .lhs file which uses inline TeX comments:

```
\begin{code} 
main = print 0
{-"$\langle$Link$\rangle$"-}
\end{code}
```

However, after compiling with lhs2TeX, I get the following errors when compiling the generated .tex file:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
l.269 \end{hscode}
\resethooks
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.
! LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.269 \end{hscode}
\resethooks
Your command was ignored.
Type I <command> <return> to replace it with another command,
or <return> to continue without it.
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
l.269 \end{hscode}
\resethooks
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.
! LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.269 \end{hscode}
\resethooks
Your command was ignored.
Type I <command> <return> to replace it with another command,
or <return> to continue without it.
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
l.269 \end{hscode}
\resethooks
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.
! LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.269 \end{hscode}
\resethooks
Your command was ignored.
```

When I remove the " marks in the inline comment, the error disappears. Anyone know what's wrong?

P.S Here's the .tex file that lhs2TeX generates:

```
\documentclass{article}%% ODER: format ==         = "\mathrel{==}"
%% ODER: format /=         = "\neq "
%
%
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{lhs2tex.lhs2tex.sty.read}%
  {\@namedef{lhs2tex.lhs2tex.sty.read}{}%
   \newcommand\SkipToFmtEnd{}%
   \newcommand\EndFmtInput{}%
   \long\def\SkipToFmtEnd#1\EndFmtInput{}%
  }\SkipToFmtEnd

\newcommand\ReadOnlyOnce[1]{\@ifundefined{#1}{\@namedef{#1}{}}\SkipToFmtEnd}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{cmtex}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmtex}{m}{n}
  {<5><6><7><8>cmtex8
   <9>cmtex9
   <10><10.95><12><14.4><17.28><20.74><24.88>cmtex10}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmtex}{m}{it}
  {<-> ssub * cmtt/m/it}{}
\newcommand{\texfamily}{\fontfamily{cmtex}\selectfont}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmtt}{bx}{n}
  {<5><6><7><8>cmtt8
   <9>cmbtt9
   <10><10.95><12><14.4><17.28><20.74><24.88>cmbtt10}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmtex}{bx}{n}
  {<-> ssub * cmtt/bx/n}{}
\newcommand{\tex}[1]{\text{\texfamily#1}}   % NEU

\newcommand{\Sp}{\hskip.33334em\relax}


\newcommand{\Conid}[1]{\mathit{#1}}
\newcommand{\Varid}[1]{\mathit{#1}}
\newcommand{\anonymous}{\kern0.06em \vbox{\hrule\@width.5em}}
\newcommand{\plus}{\mathbin{+\!\!\!+}}
\newcommand{\bind}{\mathbin{>\!\!\!>\mkern-6.7mu=}}
\newcommand{\rbind}{\mathbin{=\mkern-6.7mu<\!\!\!<}}% suggested by Neil Mitchell
\newcommand{\sequ}{\mathbin{>\!\!\!>}}
\renewcommand{\leq}{\leqslant}
\renewcommand{\geq}{\geqslant}
\usepackage{polytable}

%mathindent has to be defined
\@ifundefined{mathindent}%
  {\newdimen\mathindent\mathindent\leftmargini}%
  {}%

\def\resethooks{%
  \global\let\SaveRestoreHook\empty
  \global\let\ColumnHook\empty}
\newcommand*{\savecolumns}[1][default]%
  {\g@addto@macro\SaveRestoreHook{\savecolumns[#1]}}
\newcommand*{\restorecolumns}[1][default]%
  {\g@addto@macro\SaveRestoreHook{\restorecolumns[#1]}}
\newcommand*{\aligncolumn}[2]%
  {\g@addto@macro\ColumnHook{\column{#1}{#2}}}

\resethooks

\newcommand{\onelinecommentchars}{\quad-{}- }
\newcommand{\commentbeginchars}{\enskip\{-}
\newcommand{\commentendchars}{-\}\enskip}

\newcommand{\visiblecomments}{%
  \let\onelinecomment=\onelinecommentchars
  \let\commentbegin=\commentbeginchars
  \let\commentend=\commentendchars}

\newcommand{\invisiblecomments}{%
  \let\onelinecomment=\empty
  \let\commentbegin=\empty
  \let\commentend=\empty}

\visiblecomments

\newlength{\blanklineskip}
\setlength{\blanklineskip}{0.66084ex}

\newcommand{\hsindent}[1]{\quad}% default is fixed indentation
\let\hspre\empty
\let\hspost\empty
\newcommand{\NB}{\textbf{NB}}
\newcommand{\Todo}[1]{$\langle$\textbf{To do:}~#1$\rangle$}

\EndFmtInput
\makeatother
%
%
%
%
%
%
% This package provides two environments suitable to take the place
% of hscode, called "plainhscode" and "arrayhscode". 
%
% The plain environment surrounds each code block by vertical space,
% and it uses \abovedisplayskip and \belowdisplayskip to get spacing
% similar to formulas. Note that if these dimensions are changed,
% the spacing around displayed math formulas changes as well.
% All code is indented using \leftskip.
%
% Changed 19.08.2004 to reflect changes in colorcode. Should work with
% CodeGroup.sty.
%
\ReadOnlyOnce{polycode.fmt}%
\makeatletter

\newcommand{\hsnewpar}[1]%
  {{\parskip=0pt\parindent=0pt\par\vskip #1\noindent}}

% can be used, for instance, to redefine the code size, by setting the
% command to \small or something alike
\newcommand{\hscodestyle}{}

% The command \sethscode can be used to switch the code formatting
% behaviour by mapping the hscode environment in the subst directive
% to a new LaTeX environment.

\newcommand{\sethscode}[1]%
  {\expandafter\let\expandafter\hscode\csname #1\endcsname
   \expandafter\let\expandafter\endhscode\csname end#1\endcsname}

% "compatibility" mode restores the non-polycode.fmt layout.

\newenvironment{compathscode}%
  {\par\noindent
   \advance\leftskip\mathindent
   \hscodestyle
   \let\\=\@normalcr
   \let\hspre\(\let\hspost\)%
   \pboxed}%
  {\endpboxed\)%
   \par\noindent
   \ignorespacesafterend}

\newcommand{\compaths}{\sethscode{compathscode}}

% "plain" mode is the proposed default.
% It should now work with \centering.
% This required some changes. The old version
% is still available for reference as oldplainhscode.

\newenvironment{plainhscode}%
  {\hsnewpar\abovedisplayskip
   \advance\leftskip\mathindent
   \hscodestyle
   \let\hspre\(\let\hspost\)%
   \pboxed}%
  {\endpboxed%
   \hsnewpar\belowdisplayskip
   \ignorespacesafterend}

\newenvironment{oldplainhscode}%
  {\hsnewpar\abovedisplayskip
   \advance\leftskip\mathindent
   \hscodestyle
   \let\\=\@normalcr
   \(\pboxed}%
  {\endpboxed\)%
   \hsnewpar\belowdisplayskip
   \ignorespacesafterend}

% Here, we make plainhscode the default environment.

\newcommand{\plainhs}{\sethscode{plainhscode}}
\newcommand{\oldplainhs}{\sethscode{oldplainhscode}}
\plainhs

% The arrayhscode is like plain, but makes use of polytable's
% parray environment which disallows page breaks in code blocks.

\newenvironment{arrayhscode}%
  {\hsnewpar\abovedisplayskip
   \advance\leftskip\mathindent
   \hscodestyle
   \let\\=\@normalcr
   \(\parray}%
  {\endparray\)%
   \hsnewpar\belowdisplayskip
   \ignorespacesafterend}

\newcommand{\arrayhs}{\sethscode{arrayhscode}}

% The mathhscode environment also makes use of polytable's parray 
% environment. It is supposed to be used only inside math mode 
% (I used it to typeset the type rules in my thesis).

\newenvironment{mathhscode}%
  {\parray}{\endparray}

\newcommand{\mathhs}{\sethscode{mathhscode}}

% texths is similar to mathhs, but works in text mode.

\newenvironment{texthscode}%
  {\(\parray}{\endparray\)}

\newcommand{\texths}{\sethscode{texthscode}}

% The framed environment places code in a framed box.

\def\codeframewidth{\arrayrulewidth}
\RequirePackage{calc}

\newenvironment{framedhscode}%
  {\parskip=\abovedisplayskip\par\noindent
   \hscodestyle
   \arrayrulewidth=\codeframewidth
   \tabular{@{}|p{\linewidth-2\arraycolsep-2\arrayrulewidth-2pt}|@{}}%
   \hline\framedhslinecorrect\\{-1.5ex}%
   \let\endoflinesave=\\
   \let\\=\@normalcr
   \(\pboxed}%
  {\endpboxed\)%
   \framedhslinecorrect\endoflinesave{.5ex}\hline
   \endtabular
   \parskip=\belowdisplayskip\par\noindent
   \ignorespacesafterend}

\newcommand{\framedhslinecorrect}[2]%
  {#1[#2]}

\newcommand{\framedhs}{\sethscode{framedhscode}}

% The inlinehscode environment is an experimental environment
% that can be used to typeset displayed code inline.

\newenvironment{inlinehscode}%
  {\(\def\column##1##2{}%
   \let\>\undefined\let\<\undefined\let\\\undefined
   \newcommand\>[1][]{}\newcommand\<[1][]{}\newcommand\\[1][]{}%
   \def\fromto##1##2##3{##3}%
   \def\nextline{}}{\) }%

\newcommand{\inlinehs}{\sethscode{inlinehscode}}

% The joincode environment is a separate environment that
% can be used to surround and thereby connect multiple code
% blocks.

\newenvironment{joincode}%
  {\let\orighscode=\hscode
   \let\origendhscode=\endhscode
   \def\endhscode{\def\hscode{\endgroup\def\@currenvir{hscode}\\}\begingroup}
   %\let\SaveRestoreHook=\empty
   %\let\ColumnHook=\empty
   %\let\resethooks=\empty
   \orighscode\def\hscode{\endgroup\def\@currenvir{hscode}}}%
  {\origendhscode
   \global\let\hscode=\orighscode
   \global\let\endhscode=\origendhscode}%

\makeatother
\EndFmtInput
%

\begin{document}\section{}Precis 0
\newline{}\subsubsection*{\texttt{test0.tweave:}}\begin{hscode}\SaveRestoreHook
\column{B}{@{}>{\hspre}l<{\hspost}@{}}%
\column{E}{@{}>{\hspre}l<{\hspost}@{}}%
\>[B]{}\Varid{main}\mathrel{=}\Varid{print}\;\mathrm{0}{}\<[E]%
\\
\>[B]{}$\langle$Link$\rangle${}\<[E]%
\ColumnHook
\end{hscode}\resethooks
\section{}Precis 1 
\newline{}\subsubsection*{\texttt{test0.tweave:}}\begin{hscode}\SaveRestoreHook
\column{B}{@{}>{\hspre}l<{\hspost}@{}}%
\column{E}{@{}>{\hspre}l<{\hspost}@{}}%
\>[B]{}\Varid{accum}\;\Varid{i}\mathrel{=}\Varid{id}{}\<[E]%
\ColumnHook
\end{hscode}\resethooks
\end{document}
```

Comment: How about posting the `.tex` file, that would make it easiest to see what's going on. What do you intend this to yield, anyway?

Comment: The comment might just be incompatible with the code block. Is it necessary for it to be inside or could you just move it out, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{-" ... "-}` construct is quite low-level. It drops you in the environment TeX currently is in, which happens to be math mode already. So the solution to your problem is simple. Write the code to be inserted as if you are in math mode.

A different option is to use a normal comment, but make the comment characters invisible using `\invisiblecomments`. Normal comments are typeset as text by lhs2TeX.

The following complete lhs2TeX document demonstrates both options:

```
\documentclass{article}

%include polycode.fmt

\begin{document}

% Assume you are in math mode already:
\begin{code} 
main = print 0
{-"\langle\text{Link}\rangle"-}
\end{code}

% This works, too:
\invisiblecomments
\begin{code}
main = print 0
{- $\langle$Link$\rangle$ -}
\end{code}

\end{document}
```